# Texture "resets"?

Tags: texturing

First of, I'm very new to blender.

Currently I'm trying to apply a texture to a wall. For doing this, I followed the steps for the textures in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2Cb-5PEqGo.

The texture didn't quite fit at first, so I messed a lot with the scaling and offset, and got to a pretty decent result. Now I've only got one issue left, please refer this screenshot:
[image: problem]

As you can see, the texture fits the "grid" (sorry, I don't really know the terminology) perfectly for about 4 times, but then it resets or something for some odd reason. I've been trying to figure out what causes this, but I've honestly no clue. I'm at a loss as to what I should look up as well, because... I don't understand what's happening here.

I hope someone can help me.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want you to understand this is a workaround for your specific problem, not a real solution. You need to understand UV mapping to really solve this in any case.

This said, let's go!
Here is a shape like yours.
[image]

Go in front orthographic view with <kbd>1</kbd> (front view) and <kbd>5</kbd> (orthographic)
[image]
Now select wireframe view <kbd>Z</kbd> and face selection mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or use menus
[image]
Box select <kbd>B</kbd> your vertical faces
[image]
Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> with cube projection as said in the tutorial
[image]
On the left panel (<kbd>T</kbd> if hidden) check clip and scale to bounds
[image]

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation along with those screenshots were perfectly clear for a newb such as myself!

Comment: We've all been newbs, welcome in the blender family :)